# Antivirus threat detected when doing HttpWebRequests

Tags: c#, security, httpwebrequest, antivirus

I am creating crawler just for pratice and I get something like this every few thousand sites:

### [image]

What kind of maliciuos software/script can be executed on my PC this way and is there some way to protect myself directly from code?

Comment: If all you are doing is crawling the site and not executing anything then you should be fine.

Comment: @slugster I am just pulling HTML from response nothing else, It was wierd to me to since I am not executing any scripts or doing something similar, but why is AVG going crazy?

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/security/archive/2012/07/19/the-rise-of-the-black-hole-exploit-kit-the-importance-of-keeping-all-software-up-to-date.aspx

Comment: AVG is either looking at files on disk, or the network traffic, and seeing an attack file - it doesn't wait to see if the application doing the transfer is actually vulnerable. e.g. It would block an IE vulnerability in Firefox as well. (Assuming it's scanning network traffic that is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sites you are crawling contain the Blackhole Exploit Kit.  AVG advertises [59%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackhole_exploit_kit) ([28% from Sophos](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/exploring-the-blackhole-exploit-kit-14/)) of all web exploits it finds are of type Blackhole Exploit Kit.  Since your program is downloading the webpage like a browser, the monitoring service in AVG is alerting you of the threat coming down the pipe, unaware that it is harmlessly being thrown away.  Assuming you are not rending what you are downloading in a process that loads/executes JavaScript, you are perfectly safe.

Comment: Just one more thing, is there way to indetify such sites so I don't add them to database?

Comment: I don't believe you can do anything built in (and I'm unaware of any exposed APIs in AVG), but you could utilize the [Google Safe Browsing API](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/) and check each site prior to indexing it.

Comment: Thanks, Safe Browsing API looks good but might add too much overhead for my needs, but it will have to do if I don't find other lightweight solutions such as some antivirus API as you mentioned or somekind of keywords to look for in scripts.